# What does it mean to expand "$z^n$ around $1/2$"

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, singularity

I am trying to prove that if a power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R = 1$, and $c_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $z=1$ is a singular point of $f$.

I was told that I should "use binomial theorem and expand $z^n$ around $1/2$." But what exactly does that mean?

My guess was to write:
$$f(z+\frac12) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (z+\frac12)^n$$
And then apply binomial theorem to $(z+\frac12)^n$ and check the behavior at $z = 1/2$ to show that it is not convergent there (at least I assume that would be the approach for showing it is singular)

Comment: Hint: to expand a function around $z = z_0$, the series should be in terms of powers of $(z-z_0)^n$, not $(z+z_0)^n$.

Comment: @icurays1: Ahhh okay, that makes sense. So I would want to look at the quantity $f(z - 1/2)$ and see what happens as $z \to \frac32$?